# How to add kubernetes pods label to prometheus metrics?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

There is a label like **envName=vnc** in kubernetes pod yaml file, the original metrics collected by prometheus is:

> container_memory_usage_bytes{container_name="vncserver-vscode",id="......",image="......",name="......",namespace="kube-system",pod_name="vncserver-vscode-59878ff5cf-l2dd9"} 6.28785152e+08

And I want add the label to the metrics, like this:

> container_memory_usage_bytes{container_name="vncserver-vscode",id="......",image="......",name="......",namespace="kube-system",pod_name="vncserver-vscode-59878ff5cf-l2dd9", **envName="vnc"**} 6.28785152e+08

Does prometheus support that?

Comment: Probably not going to help directly - but relabeling might help for some metrics that are discarded due to starting with double-underscore "__". An example of this is in Prometheus' github repo where they show how to preserve a pod and namespace metric: https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/main/documentation/examples/prometheus-kubernetes.yml#L267 ; Adding metrics that don't already exist prior to relabeling would need you to customise the exporter application.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to do this. You can not change/add labels in metrics that already exists.
You will need to create new scrape with desired labels.

Comment: What is meant by "create new scrape with desired labels", I am looking for a way to access the pod labels in metrics response.